# Issue adding specific URL in InsecureContentAllowedForUrls

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, policies

I am trying to add a URL to the policy InsecureContentAllowedForUrls. The URL is actually a small service that downloads files created on the fly. The service is not using any aliases but just the server name (name of the box) in the URL. So it looks like this when we try to download a file:

http://myservermachinename/repository/file.xlxs

We have tried adding these to the policy and it does not work:

*://myservermachinename:*/*
*://myservermachinename.mydomain.com:*/*

And it does not work. However, if I add the following pattern then it works:

*://[*.]mydomain.com:*/*

Any ideas why the server name itself does not work?

Answer (score 1):

A domain can be prefixed by a wildcard “`[*.]`” to match the domain or any of its subdomains. The domain in question can be a subdomain of any level.

For example, `[*.] mysite.com` will match both `mysite.com` and `subdomain.mysite.com`. It will also match any scheme, port, and path.

Comment: thank you, yes, we tried that. However, cyber security in my company does not want open wildcards for all servers. That is why we were trying with the server name only. It would not read it

Comment: Hi, what is the URL that requests the download?
Is it also myservermachinename？Or is it another URL belonging to mydomain?

Comment: May I know any update on this issue?